# Select target number of records by groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in which each record has a rank and is associated to a certain group. 
Also, there is a target number of IDs for each group.

I need to select this target number in each group with the highest ranked records.

This is an example of this data:

```
Group            Id      Rank
--------------------------------
GUADALAJARA       1       356
GUADALAJARA       2       387
PUEBLA            3       431
TIJUANA           4       315
PUEBLA            5       315
MONTERREY         6       315
MONTERREY         7       263
PUEBLA            8       356
PUEBLA            9       447
GUADALAJARA      10       356
MONTERREY        11       356
TIJUANA          12       447
PUEBLA           13       356
PUEBLA           14       387
MONTERREY        15       431
MONTERREY        16       412
MONTERREY        17       447
TIJUANA          18       263
```

And the targets for each group are:

```
Group        Records   Goal
----------------------------
GUADALAJARA     4       2
MONTERREY       6       3
PUEBLA          6       3
TIJUANA         3       2
```

For example, group Guadalajara has 4 records , and I need to select the first two highest-ranked which would be 100630487 and 133255369:

```
ID          Rank
----------------
100630487   447
133255369   387
138314098   356
114194869   356
```

I will appreciate any ideas to make this query.

Comment: Not sure how `GUADALAJARA` has 4 records and also, don't know how 447 id belongs to `GUADALAJARA` and not other groups.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. Indeed, 447 is a rank to classify records. An ID may have the same rank of other IDs

Comment: Can you see how this makes no sense to anybody other than yourself? 100630487? Where'd that come from?

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  This should help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank. I will rephrase the idea in a new question